# Spring Cloud Contract doesn't work with Spring Boot 1.4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to build a basic example using Spring Cloud Contract capabilities.

Using Spring Tool Suite wizard, to add Spring Cloud Contract I have to select Spring-Boot version 1.4.1 or higher.

However when I create a project that uses Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Spring Contract 1.0.1.RELEASE, all my integration tests fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration
```

I've also tried to download the official examples ([server](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/samples/standalone/dsl/http-server) and [consumer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/samples/standalone/dsl/http-client) projects).

Both of them works perfectly, but they're using a non stable version of Spring-Boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

When I try to change this version to 1.4.1, both of them fails with the same error.

Does anyone know how to configure Spring Cloud Contract? Is there any example over there?

Comment: I'd guess that one or more jars were corrupted when Maven downloaded your Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE dependencies. Try clearing your Maven cache and running the example again.

Comment: Yes! That was so wierd. After deleting my entire repository folder twice, it worked again.

Comment: Of course you can!